# function for delete nodes of tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

good I am making a tree using primeng, I am doing the functions to be able to delete a node from the tree, I already have this function made that works well when I want to delete a node that has no children, and also when it only has a single child, but I giving problems when deleting a node that has more than one child.
I think the problem is in the for of the function but I don't quite realize that it may be

```js
this.nodos = {
            Estado: true, //Booleano
            Respuesta: 'ok', //string
            Dato: [
                {
                    id_nodo: 1, //int
                    padre: undefined, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 1', //String (nombre de la función)
                    menu: 'menu', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true },
                    id_funcion: 1, //int
                    orden: 1,//int
                    principal: true //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 2, //int
                    padre: 1, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 2', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 2', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 2, //int
                    orden: 2, //int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 3, //int
                    padre: 1, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 3', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 3', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 3, //int
                    orden: 3,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 4, //int
                    padre: 1, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 4', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 4', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 4, //int
                    orden: 4,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 5, //int
                    padre: 3, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 5', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 5', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 5, //int
                    orden: 5,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 6, //int
                    padre: 2, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 6', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 6', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 6, //int
                    orden: 6,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 7, //int
                    padre: 3, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 7', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 7', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 7, //int
                    orden: 7,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 8, //int
                    padre: undefined, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 8', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 8', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 8, //int
                    orden: 8,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 9, //int
                    padre: 8, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 9', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 9', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 9, //int
                    orden: 9,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 10, //int
                    padre: undefined, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 10', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 10', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 10, //int
                    orden: 10,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
                {
                    id_nodo: 11, //int
                    padre: 10, //undefined o int
                    funcion: 'funcion 11', //String (nombre de la función) lo que hay que mostrar en los recuadros
                    menu: 'menu 11', //String (titulo de la funcion)
                    permitidos: { pasar_a_manual: true, cancelar: false, estado_servicio: true }, //array de booleanos
                    id_funcion: 11, //int
                    orden: 11,//int
                    principal: false //booleano que identifica si el nodo es principal o no
                },
            ]
        }
        
        
        //Cartel Sweet Alert Error

    mostrarCartelError(titulo, contenido) {
        Swal({
            title: '<b style="color:#000;">' + titulo + '</b>',
            html: '<b style="color:#000;">' + contenido + '</b>',
            type: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
            background: 'rgb(0, 120, 106)',
            confirmButtonColor: '#78cbf2',
            timer: 10000
        })
    }

    //Cartel Sweet Alert Correcto

    mostrarCartelBien(titulo, contenido) {
        Swal({
            title: '<b style="color:#000;">' + titulo + '</b>',
            html: '<b style="color:#000;">' + contenido + '</b>',
            type: 'success',
            confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
            background: 'rgb(0, 120, 106)',
            confirmButtonColor: '#78cbf2',
            timer: 10000
        })
    }
    
    
    //Variables para la funcion del nodo seleccionado
    label: any
    dataname: any;
    padre: any

    //Funcion si se selecciona un nodo
    onNodeSelect(event) {
        

        var label = event.node.data.id_nodo

        var dataname = event.node.data.name

        var padre = event.node.data.padre

        //muestro los datos del arbol en la tabla
        this.label = label
        this.dataname = dataname
        this.padre = padre

    }
    
    // funcion para borrar un nodo
    borrarNodo(lista,idnodo) {

        //this.mostrarCartelBien("Correcto", "nodo borrado con éxito")

        //indice del nodo a borrar 
        let indice_nodo_borrar = lista.map((_, i) => i).filter(e => lista[e].id_nodo === idnodo);


        //indices de los nodos hijos a borrar 
        let indice_nodo_borrar_hijos = lista.map((_, i) => i).filter(e => lista[e].padre === idnodo);
       
       

        //indice parseado a int del indice del nodo a borrar
        let indice_nodo_borrar_parseado = parseInt(indice_nodo_borrar)

        

        //Si tiene hijos le aviso al usuario que se van a borrar los hijos del nodo seleccionado
        if(indice_nodo_borrar_hijos.length > 0){
            

            Swal({
                title: '<b style="color:#000;">Atención</b>',
                html: '<h5 style="color:#000;">Si borra este nodo también borrara su hijos ¿Desea Continuar?</h5>',
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Si, borrar',
                background: 'rgb(0, 120, 106)',
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            }).then((result) => {
                if(result.value){
                    for (let i = 0; i < indice_nodo_borrar_hijos.length; i++) {
                        
                        //Borro el nodo 
                        this.nodos.Dato.splice(indice_nodo_borrar_parseado,1)
        
                        //Borro los hijos del nodo 
                        this.nodos.Dato.splice(indice_nodo_borrar_hijos[i],1)
                        
                        //Actualizo el árbol
                        this.armarArbol(this.nodos.Dato)
                    }
        
                }
            })
            
         //Si no tiene hijos solo borro el nodo seleccionado
        }
        else{
            Swal({
                title: '<b style="color:#000;">Atención</b>',
                html: '<h5 style="color:#000;">¿Seguro que quiere borrar este nodo?</h5>',
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Si, borrar',
                background: 'rgb(0, 120, 106)',
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            }).then((result) => {
                if(result.value){
                    console.log("no tiene hijos")
                    this.nodos.Dato.splice(indice_nodo_borrar_parseado,1)
                    this.armarArbol(this.nodos.Dato)
                }
            })
            
        }
       
    }
```

```css
//Boton editar tag
.btn-editar{
  background-color:#00786a;
}

//boton nuevo tag
.btn-nuevotag{
  color: #00786a;
  font: 120% Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}


.titulo-tipo-tag{
  font: 140% Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.titulo-mensajes{
  color: #414141;
  font: 22px Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 163px;
}

//item barra
/*.item-barra{
  font: 120% Roboto;
}*/

//Estilos arbol
.company.ui-organizationchart .ui-organizationchart-node-content.ui-person {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;
}

.node-header,.node-content {
  padding: .5em .7em;
}

.node-header {
  background-color: #495ebb;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.node-content {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #404e91;
}

.node-content img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.department-cfo {
  background-color: #00786a;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bolder;
}


.department-coo {
  background-color: #a534b6 !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.department-cto {
  background-color: #e9286f !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ui-person .ui-node-toggler {
  color: #495ebb !important;
}

.department-cto .ui-node-toggler {
  color: #8a0a39 !important;
}


.node-parent{
  background-color: #e9286f !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}


.boton{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<mat-tab label="Árbol">

            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex">
                <!-- Grafico de Arbol-->

                <div class="col-md-8 mt-4">
                    <mat-tab-group >
                           <mat-tab *ngFor="let lista of lista_arboles; let indice = index" label="{{indice}}">
                               <div class="mt-3 pt-3">
                                    <p-organizationChart [value]="lista" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode"
                                        (onNodeSelect)="onNodeSelect($event)" (onNodeUnselect)="onNodeUnSelect($event)"
                                        styleClass="company">
                                        <ng-template let-node pTemplate="person">
                                            <div class="node-header ui-corner-top">{{node.label}}</div>
                                            <div class="node-content">
                                                <div>{{ node.data.name }}</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </ng-template>
                                        <ng-template let-node pTemplate="department">
                                            {{ node.label }}
                                        </ng-template>
                                    </p-organizationChart>
                                </div>
                            </mat-tab>
        
                    </mat-tab-group>
                </div>

               

                <!-- Fin Graficos de arbol dinamicos -->

                <!-- Tabla dinamica de nodos -->
                <div class="col-md-4 mt-4">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead class="text-white" style="background-color: #00786a;">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <th class="font-weight-bolder" colspan="4">Nodo Seleccionado</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id Nodo</th>
                                <th>Funcion</th>
                                <th>Nodo Padre</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td ngDefaultControl name="label" [(ngModel)]="label" [innerHTML]="label"></td>
                                <td ngDefaultControl name="dataname" [(ngModel)]="dataname" [innerHTML]="dataname"></td>
                                <td ngDefaultControl name="padre" [(ngModel)]="padre" [innerHTML]="padre"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            data-placement="top" title="Agregar Nodo"
                                            (click)="!label ? abrirModalAgregarNodo(modal_nuevo_nodo) : abrirModalAgregarNodoHijo(modal_nuevo_nodo_hijo) ">
                                            <img src="../assets/images/btn_nuevo_usuario.png" />
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar nodo" [disabled]="!label" (click)="abrirModalEditarNodo(modal_editar_nodo)">
                                            <img src="../assets/images/btn_editar.png" alt="Editar nodo" />
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"title="Borrar nodo" [disabled]="!label" (click)="borrarNodo(nodos.Dato,label)">
                                            <img src="../assets/images/ic_trash.png" height="24px" alt="Borrar nodo" />
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <table style="margin-top: 50px;" class="table table-striped">

                        <thead class="text-white" style="background-color: #00786a;">
                            <tr style="font-weight: bolder;">
                                <th>Id Nodo</th>
                                <th>Funcion</th>
                                <th>Nodo Padre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let tree of this.nodos.Dato; let index = index;">
                                <th title="Id nodo" scope="row">{{ tree.id_nodo }}</th>
                                <td title="Nombre la función del nodo">{{ tree.funcion }}</td>
                                <td title="Nodo padre">{{ tree.padre }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <!-- Fin tabla dinamica de nodos -->
            </div>

        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Some details are missing that would help. What is `borroNodo()` passed? Is it the entire list and the index to _borro_ or is a subset of the entire list? Can you help with these details please?

Comment: Hi, lista = this.nodos.Dato and idnodo = id_nodo property of each element in the array this.nodos.Dato

Comment: Thanks. So it is not necessary to call `.splice()` in a loop.You have the starting index and the length for both the nodes and children nodes, so you should simply be able to splice out those nodes with a single statement for each.

Comment: Thanks, then I would have to remove the splice method from the for?

Comment: Isolate the id of the parent to be deleted first. Then, using recursion, loop through each of the children to find each other child of that child in the tree. That is all the belongs in the loop. Once you have a list of every `id` to delete, the call `splice` only once with the index of the staring node and the length of the list.

Comment: Any clue or link that you can give me? because I was trying something but I have not been able to advance for 3 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've provided a solution below. In this example, I've deleted `id_nodo` `1`. But this will work for any node id.

1. `toDeleteList` will hold the `id_nodo`s to delete
2. Push the base `id` onto the list
3. Filter the data for all direct children of the base `id` and return their `id`
4. Add those to the list
5. For each direct child, call this function to repeat the process
6. After the entire tree is scanned for children, filter the `data` array to remove any in the `toDeleteList`
7. return the filtered list, leaving the original array unaltered

```js
const data=[{id_nodo:1,padre:null},{id_nodo:2,padre:1},{id_nodo:3,padre:1},{id_nodo:4,padre:1},{id_nodo:5,padre:3},{id_nodo:6,padre:2},{id_nodo:7,padre:3},{id_nodo:8,padre:null},{id_nodo:9,padre:8},{id_nodo:10,padre:null},{id_nodo:11,padre:10}];

let toDeleteList = [];
function deleteNode(id){
  toDeleteList.push(id);
  data.filter(d =>d.padre === id)
    .forEach(child=>{
      toDeleteList.push(child.id_nodo);
      deleteNode(child.id_nodo);
    });
  return data.filter(d=>!toDeleteList.includes(d.id_nodo));
}
const result = deleteNode(1);
console.log(result);
```